# Hybris : How to create addons for acceleratorservices extension?

Tags: ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to Hybris environment. i'm working on add-ons concept in Hybris. I can able to create addons for storefront but my question is how to create addons for acceleratorservices extension. I have tried the usual method but that is not working.
(ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="{addonName}" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="acceleratorservices"). When i compile my system it is throwing cyclic reference error. So can anyone tell me like how to create addons for acceleratorservices extension.

Any sort answer is welcome from Hybris expert. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should create custom extension (define dependency in extensioninfo.xml file) instead of addon. Addon is mainly used for extending storefront functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Addon is used to extends the functionnality of templates (extensions starting with y). In your case acceleratorservices is just a dependency of storefront. So you should just use spring to override/extends the features of acceleratorservices  you need.

To do it well, you class must extends the one from acceleratorservices  that you want to modify. Then depending on your needs, add or override methods.
Finally update your sping configuration with "aliases" to replace the bean reference by your new implementation.

Comment: (hybris/bin/ext-accelerator/acceleratorservices/src/de/hybris/platform/acceleratorservices/addonsupport) I have found this, why they have provided this if they do not support addons. i have also gone through project.properties of acceleratorservices where i could find the path for the acceleratoraddon.

Comment: @Barath It's not related. It's used to configure addon to load in yacceleratorstorefront from acceleratorservices. It's not a clue to acceleratorservices be an addon or something to include addons in. I may be wrong but I strongly recommend to use bean injection than addon when not speaking of frontend.

Comment: okay let me come to the point, (acceleratorservices/web/src/de/hybris/platform/acceleratorservices/web/payment/controllers/SilentOrderPostMockController.java) In this file they are getting the credit card details(unmasked) and they are masking it. Now, i want to get the card details(unmasked) here and i want to send that to my payment service provider which i can do that successfully. But what my thought is to create add-on and make that changes in my add-on. is it possible? or else is there any other way to get the unmasked card details??

Comment: @Barath First you're not supposed to send credit card info to your system if your not PCI compliant. Then if you want to achieve that then just don't use SilentOr‌​derPostMockControlle‌​r. Just post your form to your own controller (so update storefront and not accelratorservices). Also on StackOverflow if you have a new question, ask it in a separated thread. Your original question is how to generate addon for acceleratorservices.

Comment: Thanks mate. i'll post my questions in a new thread hereafter.